# In "Aggregate" tool, concatenate function and \n delimiter doesn't result in break line

Tags: qgis, aggregate, concatenation, breaklines

I am encountering problems with the 'Aggregate' tool and the 'concatenate' function with the '\n' delimiter. The process is not resulting in a line break as expected.

Please see the screenshot of the parameters and the result.
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I use '\n' in a label expression or even in the 'Field calculator' tool, it works. This process is not causing any problems for my colleagues.

I have tried it on stable version 3.22 and on the new version 3.28. I have uninstalled all versions and reinstalled them.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delimiter text seems to be considered as plain text.

There are some workarounds:

1. you can keep the `,` delimiter and instruct to break your label on commas

[image]

2. you can add the line break to the text to be aggregated (not the delimiter), with an empty delimiter. This however will add an extra line break after the last item

[image]